# Как сместить все символы на 1-н назад циклично

Tags: c++

Надо сместить все символы на 1-н назад циклично.

Это код с ассемблерной вставкой, она работает, нужно написать такое же внутри программы, но на языке си++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <ctime>
void MoveASM(char* str, size_t cnt)
{`size_t len = strnlen_s(str, 32) - 1;
__asm
{
    push eax
    push ecx
        push ebx
        mov ecx, cnt
        lbl1 :
    push ecx
        xor eax, eax
        mov ebx, str
        mov al, byte ptr[ebx]
        push eax
        mov ecx, len
        mov esi, str
        inc esi
        mov edi, str
        rep movsb
        pop eax
        mov ebx, str
        add ebx, len
        mov byte ptr[ebx], al
        pop ecx
        dec ecx
        jecxz ext
        jmp lbl1
        ext :
     pop ebx
        pop ecx
        pop eax
     }
  }
 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
char *str = new char[32];
std::cout << "Введите строку:\n";
std::cin >> str;
srand(time(0));
MoveASM(str, 5);
std::cout << "\nРезультат:\n"<< str;
std::cout << "\nВремя выполнения итераций на ASM: " << clock() / 1000.0;
std::cout << "\n";
std::cin.get();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

[image: Резульатат]

Comment: А что у вас не получается? Покажите, пожалуйста ваш код.

Comment: Символы где? В массиве или строке? И вообще какой это предмет?

Comment: Никто ваш ассемблерный код не будет переводить, лучше покажите изначальный и конечный вариант строки после преоброзования

Comment: Не забудьте поставить галочку напротив правильного ответа

Answer (score 3):

```
std::string str = "string";
std::rotate(str.begin(), str.begin() + 1, str.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

Раз C++ и символы - это скорее всего строка (да даже если и не строка), тогда я бы предложил:

```
std::string str = "string";
//в одну сторону
str.append(1,str[0]);
str.erase(0,1);
//в другую сторону
str = str[str.size()-1] + str;
str.erase(str.size()-1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если после сдвига строки ненужное можно отсечь, то код может быть таким:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void MoveLeft(string & s, const size_t sz){
    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());

    for (size_t lsz = 0; lsz < sz; lsz++)
        s.pop_back();

    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
}

int main(){
    string s = "abcdef";

    MoveLeft(s, 2);

    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

результат:

[image: результат]

---

**Обновление: если нужно двигать вправо и замещать выходом символов вначале то можно поступить так:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void RotateRight(string & s, const size_t sz){
    for (size_t lsz = 0; lsz < sz; lsz++){
        reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
        s.push_back(s[0]);
        reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
        s.pop_back();
    }
}

int main(){
    string s = "privet";

    RotateRight(s, 2);

    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

вывод:

[image: вывод]

Comment: нужно первый символ перенести в конец строки

Comment: тогда используйте ответ @ixSci

Comment: или смотрите мой обновленный ответ

Comment: Спасибо за решение задачи!

Answer (score 0):

```
auto firstElement = array[0];
for(i = 0; i < count - 1; ++i)
    array[i] = array[i+1];
array[count - 1] = firstElement;
```

Но вас сейчас заминусуют)

Comment: Больше похоже на смещение вперед. И из кода абсолютно не понятно откуда берется переменная `count`.

Comment: Я считаю, что "назад" - это влево (потому что пишу слева направо и мне так кажется логично). count очевидно размер массива. P.S. Какой вопрос - такой ответ

Comment: Тогда слева это начало, а конец справа. Как по мне так назад, это значит к концу.

Comment: Тонкости русского языка. Увеличение индексов от 0 и вверх, то есть если идти "вперед" по массиву - то это от 0 и дальше => назад наоборот